# Add icon in Navigatior drawer.. (Follow from android hive)

Tags: java, android

im using this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/ for create navigation drawer, but how to add icon in every title we have?
please someone help thanks

btw im using fragment

FragmentDrawer.java

```
public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
    List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();


    // preparing navigation drawer items
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
        navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
        data.add(navItem);
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // drawer labels
    titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
    icons = getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

}
```

string.xml

```
<string name="nav_item_home">Home</string>
<string name="nav_item_friends">Friends</string>
<string name="nav_item_notifications">Messages</string>
<string name="nav_item_calculator">BMI Calculator</string>
<string name="nav_item_listview">Test Json</string>
<string name="nav_item_testabs">Test Tabs</string>


<!-- navigation drawer item labels  -->
<string-array name="nav_drawer_labels">
    <item>@string/nav_item_home</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_friends</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_notifications</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_calculator</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_listview</item>
    <item>@string/nav_item_testabs</item>
</string-array>

<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/arm1</item>
    <item>@drawable/abs2</item>
    <item>@drawable/back</item>
    <item>@drawable/leg</item>
    <item>@drawable/shoulder</item>
    <item>@drawable/achest</item>
</array>
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_notifications);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CalculatorFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_calculator);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new MovieFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_listview);
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new TabFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_testabs);
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

NavDrawwerItem.java

```
public class NavDrawerItem {
private boolean showNotify;
private String title;
private int icon;

public NavDrawerItem() {

}

public NavDrawerItem(boolean showNotify, String title, int icon) {
    this.showNotify = showNotify;
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public boolean isShowNotify() {
    return showNotify;
}

public void setShowNotify(boolean showNotify) {
    this.showNotify = showNotify;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getIcon(){
    return this.icon;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setIcon(int icon){
    this.icon = icon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Way is to Use [**NavigationView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) which is in support lib.

### see this [Link](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html) for demo

you have to Create menu file for item is navigation

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/inbox"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox_black"
        android:title="@string/inbox_string" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/starred"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_black"
        android:title="@string/starred_string" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sent_mail"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_send_black"
        android:title="@string/sent_mail_string" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drafts"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drafts_black"
        android:title="@string/draft_string" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/allmail"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black"
        android:title="@string/all_mail_string" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/trash"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_black"
        android:title="@string/trash_string" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spam"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_error_black"
        android:title="@string/spam_string" />

</group>
```

Comment: Thanks! btw, im already use thoose way to create navigation drawer